# Pagos Marketplace Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin, tpv

pues planteo la siguiente duda, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme con esto, pues ando un poco liado.

Resulta que tengo un Marketplace montado con woocomerce y WordPress. Hasta ahí todo correcto. La duda es que quiero hacer que los pagos de este Marketplace vayan instantáneos a cada vendedor, pongo un ejemplo:

Cliente compra varios Productos de varios Vendedores, este cliente paga y automáticamente una vez finalizado el pago, cada vendedor tiene su dinero en su cuenta.

En definitiva yo no quiero controlar el dinero de mis vendedores, por motivos de darle confianza a ellos y seguridad, quiero que el dinero de sus ventas vayan a ellos directamente.

La verdad no se por donde meterle mano, si hay algún plugin que ya lo haga.

Para el Marketplace uso el plugin WC Lovers que la verdad lo veo muy completo ó no se si me recomendáis otro.

Saludo y gracias de antemanos amigos!.

La página con la que necesito ayuda: https://latiendadelartesano.com

Comment: No creo que eso sea posible, por lo general para recibir un pago debes usar una pasarela de pagos, podrías mostrarle a tus clientes cuanto han vendido, pero no creo que sea posible que automáticamente el pago se les envié a ellos, ya que por lo general lo que configuras es tu cuenta proporcionada por la pasarela de pagos, esta recibe el dinero y luego lo envía a tu cuenta de banco, así que tendrias que manualmente pagarle a cada vendedor, aunque podrías hablar con tu pasarela de pago para automatizar el proceso, pero difícilmente se hará tal y como lo pides.

Comment: Gracias antes de nada. Leyendo por ahí ví algo con PayPal. pero no quiero paypal, pues cada vendedor de mi tienda tienen sus pasarelas de pago. lo que yo quiero es implementar a cada vendedor su pasarela. y a lo mejor lo más tedioso, sería hacer como ir pangando vendedor a vendedor. con su pasarela. pero lo veo muy lioso para los clientes.

Comment: Eso seria complicado, en un sitio con woocommerce no creo que sea posible, sin embargo si seria posible si cada vendedor tuviera una instalación en subdominio por ejemplo, sin embargo toma en cuenta que ellos deben de tener una pasarela propia, eso significa que deben de conseguir una, proceso que puede llevar algo de tiempo si usas una de tu pais, en todo caso, mi recomendacion es que contrates a un desarrollador, es quien te puede dar una mejor respuesta

Comment: tendría que ser un plugin de vendors que asocie las keys del método de pago al usuario vendedor, en conjunción con una pasarela de pagos que por medio de oauth le permita a cada vendedor ( desde el panel de su cuenta ) autorizar y grabar las keys y así enlazarlas. wc vendors tiene algo parecido con stripe